# Show .tpl loop in reverse

Tags: php, loops

I have a loop:

```
{section name=nr loop=$payment_results}
Stuff goes here...
{/section}
```

Currently the results are shown ascending (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc). I want to reverse the loop and show them descending (... 5, 4, 3, 2, 1).

Sorry if this has been asked, I didn't find any viable solutions.

*** SOLUTION ***

Add step=-1 to the loop;

```
{section name=nr loop=$payment_results step=-1}
Stuff goes here...
{/section}
```

Also, if you want to limit how many items to display add max=30 (or whatever number) to the loop.

Source: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.section.tpl

Why did someone vote this down? Nobody could help and when I found a solution you vote it down? That's low man.

Comment: What kind of code is that? Is this really related to some .NET library? And why don't change the order in `$payment_results`?

Comment: Can't change $payment_results because the php part of the code is encoded (I purchased the script). I need to find a way to reverse it within the loop.

Comment: And what kind of templating language is that? If you could add that to your question, we could figure out if there is some possibility embedded in the templating logic

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer. And is there any reason for using `step=-2` instead of `-1`?

Comment: Yes it should be `-1` Duly noted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_reverse`:

```
{section name=nr loop=$payment_results|@array_reverse}
```

Comment: Didn't reverse it. Any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can can do it within the template, but if you have access to where `$payment_results` is defined, you can reverse the array in PHP before passing it to the template:

```
$payment_results = array_reverse($payment_results);
```

PHP function reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: It doesn't work if I do `{section name=nr loop=array_reverse($payment_results)}
Stuff goes here...
{/section}` or if I do `{$payment_results = array_reverse($payment_results)} {section name=nr loop=$payment_results}
Stuff goes here...
{/section}` How can I make it work in a .tpl file?

Comment: I can't change it in the .php file, unfortunately.